# Sybase.pm and ASE 15.7

Tags: perl, sybase

I am upgrading from ASE 12.5.4 to ASE 15.7.  Currently we are using the Sybase.pm from Micheal Peppler for DBI.  Upon upgrading ASE to 15.7, the perl script no longer work.

Does the Sybase.pm need to be recompiled against the new Open Client libraries?

Thanks for the help

Comment: is the path to the installation specified correctly?

Comment: When you say installation path, do you mean the Open Client libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue.  Sybase.pm had to be recompiled using the new Open Client libraries.